# Xamarin - get file path of image saved to photo library

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am using Xamarin to save images to the iPhones photo library and I want get the file path of these images.

Below is the code that allows me to get the path of images saved to the applications tmp directory.

```
string filepath = Path.GetTempPath() + "test.png";
Image.Save(filepath);
```

> **Is there a way I can get the file path of an image saved to the photo library?**

```
Image.ToUIImage().SaveToPhotosAlbum((image, error) => { 

     //GET THE FILE PATH OF image HERE
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access the Photos library using normal File I/O. Beside the privacy concerns, the underlying data is not necessarily stored on the device. You have to use the Photos framework and `PHAsset` / `PHImageManager` and related classes. [This post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/build-great-photo-experiences-in-ios-8-with-photokit/) shows several standard use-cases.

Comment: Appreciate the insight. Is there any Xamarin classes available that will allow applications to integrate with Apple's new Files app?

Comment: Yes, Xamarin has complete support. See [this discussion](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/104295/how-to-open-files-app-ios-11-programmatically) for some sample code.